# html css border still shows

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code which seems to still show an outline around the tables.

How do I remove this? any help much appreciated!

```html
<table height=\"200\" width=\"133\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style="position:absolute;top:33px;left:50px;border-style: none;border-collapse: collapse;outline: none;padding:none;">

<td width="100" height="133"><img src='<?php echo $imageurl[$key];?>' height="133" width="100"></td><td width="27" height="133"><?php if($status[$key]=="Busy"){ ?><img src="/readerfeedincall.png" height="133" width="33"><?php } else { ?><img src="readeravailablebox.png" height="133" width="33"><?php }?></td>

</tr>
<tr><?php if($status[$key]=="Busy"){ ?>

<td colspan="2" height="67" width="135" background="/bottomRed.png"  style="background-size: 135px 67px;background-repeat:no-repeat;" align="center"><font size="4" face="Helvetica"><?php echo $displayname[$key];?></font><br><font size="4" face="Helvetica">PIN </font><font size="4" face="Helvetica"><b><?php echo $agentid[$key];?></b></font></td><?php }else { ?>

<td colspan="2" height="67" width="135" background="/bottomGreen.png"  style="background-size: 135px 67px;background-repeat:no-repeat;" align="center"><font size="4" face="Helvetica"><?php echo $displayname[$key];?></font><br><br><font size="4" face="Helvetica">PIN </font><font size="4" face="Helvetica"><b><?php echo $agentid[$key];?></b></font><?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you character escaping your quotations in HTML?

Comment: Your table html is invalid. You cannot have `td` without a wrapping `tr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern way is to set border width to 0px;

```
<table height=\"200\" width=\"133\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style="position:absolute;top:33px;left:50px;border-style: none;border-collapse: collapse;outline: none;padding:none; border: 0px">
```

Furthermore: you are using slashes before some of your HTML quotes. Those probably won't work

Comment: You don't even need the `px`. Just remove the slashes.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table height="200" width="133" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="position:absolute;top:33px;left:50px;border-style: none;border-collapse: collapse;outline: none;padding:none;border:none;">

<td width="100" height="133"><img src='<?php echo $imageurl[$key];?>' height="133" width="100"></td><td width="27" height="133"><?php if($status[$key]=="Busy"){ ?><img src="/readerfeedincall.png" height="133" width="33"><?php } else { ?><img src="readeravailablebox.png" height="133" width="33"><?php }?></td>

</tr>
<tr><?php if($status[$key]=="Busy"){ ?>

<td colspan="2" height="67" width="135" background="/bottomRed.png"  style="background-size: 135px 67px;background-repeat:no-repeat;" align="center"><font size="4" face="Helvetica"><?php echo $displayname[$key];?></font><br><font size="4" face="Helvetica">PIN </font><font size="4" face="Helvetica"><b><?php echo $agentid[$key];?></b></font></td><?php }else { ?>

<td colspan="2" height="67" width="135" background="/bottomGreen.png"  style="background-size: 135px 67px;background-repeat:no-repeat;" align="center"><font size="4" face="Helvetica"><?php echo $displayname[$key];?></font><br><br><font size="4" face="Helvetica">PIN </font><font size="4" face="Helvetica"><b><?php echo $agentid[$key];?></b></font><?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just fix     `border=\"0\"`
into  `border="0"`

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add this into inside the table tag.

border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"

```
<table  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
...
</table>
```